# Force Intellij IDEA to reread all maven dependencies

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

How to force intellij idea to reread/update all dependencies specified in the pom file ?

Answer (score 463, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to find actions, and input "reload", you will find the "Reload All Maven Projects".

On a Mac, use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> instead.

Comment: Lets say I have 5 modules, all of them maven based, in a single project and I do this. Does this command apply to all modules, just the selected one, or the first one in the project when it runs?

Comment: has this changed?  I do not see a reimport on 2017.1 in Maven

Comment: @Winnemucca I just did it on 2017.2. Waiting for it to finish now.

Comment: I had to enable Maven plugin to do this.

Comment: @Winnemucca you can right click on the pom, go to Maven in the drop down, and choose Reimport.

Comment: Original import took minutes, when doing this only take 1 sec, something seems wrong with the solution (or it's my setup which is clearly not impossible).

Comment: At the time of this writing, it is now called "Reload all Maven Projects".

Comment: Is this renamed to "reload all maven projects"?

Comment: Not very wise to give a shortcut that can change from a configuration to another.

Comment: This worked for me when IntelliJ refused to update an External Library artifact to the new version that I'd declared in my POM, and insisted the method I was trying to use didn't exist. But what I'd *really* like to know is *why* IntelliJ does this from time to time. It's incredibly obnoxious, and often makes me question my sanity.

Comment: works flawlessly

Answer (score 144):

Open the "Maven Projects" tab/window and clicking the "Reimport All Maven Projects" in the upper left corner starts to reload all dependencies from their repositories. The status bar informs about the process.

What lets you think that this is not working correctly? Maybe any of the dependencies can't be load from the repository?

Comment: we have a broken habit of using a non-snapshot version for on-going development, and cross-project dependencies sometimes fail.

Comment: I'm afraid this problem depends on maven. Maven only checks for updates on SNAPSHOTs. Per definition, non-SNAPSHOT versions will never change so maven don't has to check for newer versions than this in the local repository. A (quite rude) solution would be to remove the library from the local repository before invoke maven. Then it has to reload the library.

Comment: it appears that the reimport all forces the -U flag what is what I wanted :)

Comment: I was right-clicking the parent project and doing Maven -> Reimport and hoped it'll update the dependencies of all the children, but it did not. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: To find the "Maven Projects" tab/window go to View > Tool Windows > Maven Projects

Comment: It worked for me. Thank you a lot for that. I just had to reload all maven projects and my project has successfully returned to work. It has fixed the following errors:
1 - Fatal error compiling: invalid target release
2 - Unknown lifecycle phase “build”. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format
Again, thank you a lot. You contributed to stopping 6-7 hours of continuous research!

Comment: In 2024 it's called Reload All Maven Projects

Answer (score 74):

There is also one useful setting that tells IntelliJ to check for new versions of dependencies even if the version numbers didn't change. We had a local maven repository and a snapshot project that was updated a few times but the version numbers stood the same. The problem was that IntelliJ/Maven didn't update this project because of the fixed version number.

To enable checking for a changed dependency although the version number didn't change go to the "Maven Projects" tab, select "Maven settings" and there activate "Always update snapshots".

Comment: ha! automated updates in a JAVA project...I'm going to have to say this one is NOT always a winner...and may even be frowned up w/ Maven 3+

Comment: @beauXjames.. this didn't work for me but I am exactly facing the same issue. how to resolve this.

Comment: I often go into the local repo ({user}\.m2\...) directory and delete those I know are associated with my project then let the install process go out and fetch them again from scratch so there's no version conflicts

Comment: From `help`: "Select this checkbox, if you want IntelliJ IDEA to update snapshots on sync."  In other words, it isn't fully automatic -- you have to `Synchronize` (in right-click menu or `Ctrl-Alt-Y`), but enabling this option causes it to grab updated `SNAPSHOT` versions.  WARNING: There may be other subtleties involved, like `Import Changes` -- this doesn't seem to be perfectly reproducible for me so far.  Maybe it was all in my imagination -- what does always seem to work is a full `reimport` as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 42):

**For IntelliJ IDEA 14.0**

Project > [your project name] > right click > Maven > Reimport

Answer (score 31):

In the latest IntelliJ IDEA version (2020.1.3 Ultimate Edition), You need to to click this little guy that appears on the top right of the editor window after you make a change to the pom.xml

This little guy is too small and in an unnoticeable position. I liked the previous versions where an alert shows up in the bottom right. Still can't find the option to enable auto import in this version.

[image]

**Another Option**

From the properties panel on the right, select Maven and click on the reload icon. If you do not see maven on right panel, open it from View > Tool Windows > Maven

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer !!! I feel dumb for admitting that before your hint, I was basically always shutting down my entire project and re-opening it !!!

Comment: This little guy is so small that I clicked on the close btn instead and don't know how to reopen it 0.0

Comment: If you are using Gradle, you will find a Gradle Menu Option on the right top corner above Notifications Menu Option. Then click on the first Refres like Menu Option (Reload All Gradle Projects.)

Comment: You're the real hero here. I struggled to resolve a dependency for spring-boot-starter-data-rest after modifying an existing project but this certainly did the trick. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 27):

The leftmost button (blue cycle) below also reimports all maven projects:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this comment. I see too few answers on this post that contain the word "Reload", which in this case seems to do the same thing as what I guess "Reimport" used to do.

Answer (score 25):

run this command 
`mvn -U clean install`

Comment: While this is a solution, it needs to be done from the CLI. The question is about doing it from inside IDEA.

Comment: on the IDE, you can execute a maven goal and use the command above without you opening your CLI or Terminal

Comment: That kinds of defeats the purpose of having maven integration in IDEA.

Comment: We are talking about the -U option, which is not present in IDEA. The "Reimport" option sounds like it is, but it's not.

Comment: it is present, the intellisense should even show you the description of what -U does

Comment: I see that you are referring to typing and executing a maven goal, in which case it's possible. However, I was referring to -U not being present in the built-in menu on the right ("Maven Projects").

Answer (score 21):

If the reimport does not work (i.e. doesn't remove old versions of dependencies after a pom update), there is one more chance:

- open the project settings (CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+S)
- on modules, delete all libs that you want to reimport (e.g. duplicates)
- IDEA will warn that some are still used, confirm
- Apply and select OK
- *then* reimport all maven projects.

Comment: Thanks, this works, although now the library doesn't show up under "External Libraries" at all, but the project is using the new library successfully anyway. I wonder what is wrong with IntelliJ when it can't update the External Libraries section to match the reality.

Answer (score 16):

Setting > Maven > Always update snapshots

Comment: Works for me using IJ 2020.3.2

Comment: Only this option works for me to force Maven to download the latest JAR from a remote source instead of using the one in the local .m2 repo

Comment: This should be the prerequisite to other answer with "Reload" action in IntelliJ. Or it only reload existing download artifacts in your local repo.

Answer (score 6):

Go to File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven

Select "Always update snapshots"

Answer (score 4):

I had a problem where IntelliJ was unable to compile classes, claiming that dependencies between projects were missing.
Reimporting the project as suggested in the answers of this question didn't solve the problem.
The solution for me, was:

1. remove all projects (project tab / right click on the root folder / maven / remove projects);
2. close the editor;
3. compile all projects with maven on the command line;
4. open the editor on the same project;
5. add the projects to maven again (maven tab / add maven projects (green +) / choose the root pom);

WARNING: on some projects, you might have to increment max memory for maven import (maven settings on maven tab / Importing / VM options for importer).

Answer (score 3):

If you work in IntelliJ, there are four independent ways to refresh maven repositories.
Each of them refreshes another local repository on your computer or refreshes them differently.

```
1. mvn -U clean install
2. Ctrl+Shift+A - Reimport
3. Round arrows in the Maven window

4. Ctrl+Alt+S , go to Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Repositories -choose rep - update
```

What is interesting, it is often said, that the last refresh is equal to the round arrows in the Maven window. But, according to my experience, they are absolutely different! The proof: Our large project fails the last refresh, but exists and runs happily without it. And double round arrows run OK on it.

Each of these four can help you with your problems or/and find problems of its own. For example, for running our real-life project only the first is necessary, but for testing in IntelliJ we also need 2 and 3. Surely, somebody needs 4, too. (Why else IntelliJ has it?)

Answer (score 3):

This is still an issue in 2022.

- The option *Setting > Maven > Always update snapshots* **no longer works** in IDEA 2022.2.2, probably because Maven 3 frowns upon it and IntelliJ seems to not have updated the IDE to make it function.
- A simple solution might be to be able to add *maven -U clean install* as a ***custom target*** to the Lifecycle list in the IDEA Maven tab, but if it is possible it is not clear how to do it (even after googling for days).
- A not as nice but viable solution would be to go into the ***Terminal tool*** of IDEA and typing *maven -U clean install*, but IDEA does not expose the maven command in its Terminal by default and again it is not clear how to configure it so that it would.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using version ranges for any dependencies, make sure that IntelliJ is using Maven 3 to import the project. You can find this setting in: `Settings > Maven > Importing > Use Maven3 to import project`. Otherwise you may find that SNAPSHOT versions are not imported correctly.

Answer (score 1):

For separate modules: right click on modules's pom.xml -> Reload as Maven project.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways one can do it.

- 1st Way

Go to File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools | Maven

Select "Always update snapshots"

Apply and OK

- 2nd Way

  mvn -U clean install

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, upon checking, i needed to force update snapshots to use the IDEA's maven for the project. So i commanded idea to do a `mvn clean compile -U` and my latest version of the dependency is displayed on idea... No need to remove all of the projects settings. Just do this in your ide.

[image: command idea to do a forced update snapshots and versions]

Answer (score 0):

If it is a gradle project, you can reload all maven dependencies using

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, Intellij did not update into the newer versions. In that case, I deleted the previous one from .m2 and then I ran `clean install -U`

Answer (score -1):

To remove ***all dependencies*** you can simply delete your local maven repo: `~/.m2` folder by default. Then rebuild your projects one-by-one:

```
mvn clean
mvn package
```

Answer (score -1):

I searched for the jar in `~/.gradle` and then deleted it:

```
find ~/.gradle/ -name *.jar| grep myjar
```