# IntelliJ Maven Dependency Auto Completion

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I've noticed that sometimes when I start typing in a dependency for maven, it will offer me options for dependencies I have used in the past, but not all of the time.

Is there some way to update the list of dependencies available in this list that pops up, it's actually quite handy.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, http://stackoverflow.com/q/21243039/685796

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ IDEA and Maven: Can't complete tutorial, Maven Artifact Search returns no classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243039/intellij-idea-and-maven-cant-complete-tutorial-maven-artifact-search-returns)

Answer (score 3):

Directly copying [what Meo linked to here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21243039/685796):

> Please navigate in Settings to Project settings -> Maven -> Repositories and `Update` the repo listed there. That will refresh Maven's / IntelliJ's knowledge of what Maven packages exist.