# How can I run a Maven project in Intellij Idea (and have all dependencies downloaded)?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

In Intellij IDEA I created a Maven project and added dependencies to the `pom.xml` file. However when I run the project using <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>, as with 'plain' projects, I get `ClassNotFoundException`s.

My question is: is that the proper way to run a Maven project, and have all the dependencies been downloaded? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Reload all dependencies: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and input "reimport" as an action. You will find the "Reimport All Maven Projects" option. Afterwards, rebuild the project.

Answer (score -1):

I am more experienced with setting it up on Eclipse but I believe the Intellij plugin should also offer some option to Update Maven Dependencies, which should download the jars you are missing.

In fact, a quick search I just did directed me at this post
[Force Intellij IDEA to reread all maven dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980869/force-intellij-idea-to-reread-all-maven-dependencies)

Good luck!