# Maven library issues when importing OptaPlanner project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, optaplanner

I am checking out OptaPlanner: https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner, and for some reason after cloning the project my Maven modules have an issue. I am unable to run any of the example projects because of this. I have re-cloned the project several times, and I enable Maven, but nothing has worked.

Are there some settings that I am missing? Thanks in advance!

[image]

EDIT

Thank you all for your response, but the offered solutions still do not correct this conflict. I have more details to provide you. First, I do not have offline enabled. You can see from the below screenshot. One thing I have tried is trying to "clean" and "install" from the Maven panel. This results in an attempt to download the necessarily files I need but ends with an error that I am not familiar with. I believe this is the root of the issue I am facing. I also tried the CTRL+SHIFT+A shortcut and Reimported All Maven Libraries, and this function did nothing. The results of my issue remain the same.

[image]

The last bit of information I have is that when importing optaplanner I get an error from the start. It says that one of my modules has an incorrect type and needs to be recreated. Even though I click on recreate, it never gets recreated. And I feel that this has caused the other needed Maven libraries to also not be created. Is this controlled by some sort of setting?

[image]

Comment: Try "reimporting all" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980869/force-intellij-idea-to-reread-all-maven-dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Optional: If you have a recent version of maven installed, first try `mvn clean install -DskipTests` on the command line, that way all dependencies that need to be downloaded are already there and you know that works.

Regardless, just opening the root `pom.xml` in a recent IntelliJ version should be enough. You can open the maven dock and click these two buttons in the top bar in that dock window: "Reimport all maven projects" and "Generate sources and update folders for all projects", to trigger a refresh.

**I think you have "offline mode" toggled on, preventing it to download those dependencies.** It's also a button in that maven dock window in IntelliJ.

Comment: These suggestions do not solve the issue, I have edited my question. +1 for good advice and tips

Comment: Wierd, it should just work. Can you try: open the maven dock window, tree item Profiles, enable checkbox tree item "fullProfile" and "jbossRepo".

Comment: I have checked these off. The IDE just refuses to import the Maven libraries. I am unable to run the project at all. What could effect this?

Comment: My collegue says the property `{version.org.jboss....}` hasn't been there in a while. Looks like you're using old snapshots or old code?