# IntelliJ running wrong version of SpringBoot - mvn and java jar work correctly

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am running version 2018.1.2 of IntelliJ. Whenever I run or debug my application from within IntelliJ, Springboot is running version 2.0.0.RELEASE (and erroring out). The pom.xml has the following set:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

When I run `mvn clean package`, I can see that it is running version 2.0.1.RELEASE and everything works as expected. I have also tried running `java -jar app.jar` and it is showing 2.0.1.RELEASE.

I have looked all over IntelliJ to see if there are any additional settings or places to override the version and I have found nothing. Does anyone know how to ensure the version of Springboot within IntelliJ?

Comment: Any of the answers here should probably fix it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980869/force-intellij-idea-to-reread-all-maven-dependencies

Comment: I had tried reimporting before. I just went through each of those answers and tried all of them again with no luck :/

Comment: Have you deleted .idea folder and .iml file before reimporting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the actual fix is, but I can provide the steps that resolved the issue:

- Backed up and deleted .idea folder and .iml file from project
- Reimported, build (errored immediately)
- Restored .idea folder, but deleted contents of library folder
- Reimported, mvn clean package, build (failed immediately)
- Restored library items
- Build (failed immediately)
- Mvn clean package, reimport, build (success)

None of the files or steps really changed, but this process somehow fixed things.

Answer (score 2):

I'va faced this issue when pom.xml of project contained incorrect versions in *~/.m2/repository* folder. Here is how I managed to resolve it:

1. [Only for multi-module project] Make sure that you have the same version in parent pom and in child poms in parent tag.
2. Run `mvn clean install` instead of `package`
3. Click `Reload All Maven Projects` in IntelliJ IDEA

Also you can try to remove this project manually from *~/.m2/repository* and rebuild project.