# scala not working with kafka-streams-scala and maven

Tags: java, scala, maven, build, apache-kafka

Problem is that - I have a program that builds and runs fine.  It is written in Scala and it uses the Kafka Streams DSL.  I was to use the new kafka-streams-scala package and I am using Maven right now.  I can't use SBT right now.  When I add the dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-streams-scala_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I then get all kinds of errors in the code, that already runs.  I can't even do the following import statement
`import scala.collection.JavaConverters._`.

When I do, I get the following error 
`object language is not a member of package org.apache.kafka.streams.scala`.

Why is this happeneing and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is this in IntelliJ? Have you tried doing a clean and re-build?

Comment: Yes IntelliJ.  Yes I have done that.

Comment: Where did you get that Maven config from? I think you have a problem with resolving kafka-streams-scala, probably because I don't think there is a version `2.0.0`. Try changing version to `0.2.0` and then refresh your dependencies - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980869/force-intellij-idea-to-reread-all-maven-dependencies

Comment: I think you are talking about the old Scala wrapper by Lightbend.  Anyway, if maven couldn't find it in the repository it would have given a nice error.  And here is a link to the new Scala wrapper https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams-scala_2.12/2.0.0

Comment: Ah sorry ye, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to prefix `_root_` to all the Scala core packages like for example

```
import _root_.scala.collection.JavaConverters._
```