# Error:(185, 13) java: try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.5 (use -source 7 or higher to enable try-with-resources)

Tags: java, maven

In intelij maven compiling in Java SDK 1.8 but showing automatically changes to Java SDK 1.5 and shows this error

Comment: Have you tried setting the source level to 1.8?

Comment: Have you specified java version in pom?

Comment: @SukhpalSingh yes did so it didnt work

Comment: Yes exactly @ErwinBolwidt it does the trick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your `pom.xml` file should have this, it specified the maven compiler to 1.8

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Or

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Hey did so it didnt work for me I did this work around @Dang

Comment: you should run `mvn clean install` or `mvn clean package` in command line to see if it correct, if not I think it relate to the intelij IDE.

Comment: Or you can visit [this question and answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980869/force-intellij-idea-to-reread-all-maven-dependencies) to update maven in intelji

Comment: Hi @Dang it worked but had to change the .iml file Language level to 1.8.Thanks for the support

Comment: iltelij suppose to changed the .iml file automatically after you change the `pom.xml`(the .iml file is just some config file generated by intelij and not related to your code). But I'm glad it works.

Comment: Cool brother thanks for the help marked the answer as correct