# Problems with Dependencies Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/kie/api/KieServices$Factory with Drools version 7.59.0

Tags: java, maven, drools, kie

I just started learning Drools, but I'm having a bad time with it, I'm trying a simple project, but I'm getting this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/kie/api/KieServices$Factory at com.sample.App.main(App.java:12)
```

All suggestions of Stackoverflow and other discussion did not help. Does anyone have a solution? When I use mvn clean install is BUILD SUCCESS

This is my code

com.sample.App

```
package com.sample;

import com.model.Item;
import org.kie.api.KieServices;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Rule engine");
        KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
        KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession();

        Item item = new Item("A", (float) 123.35);
        System.out.println("Item category: " + item.getCategory());
        kSession.insert(item);
        int fired = kSession.fireAllRules();
        System.out.println("Number of Rules executed: " + fired);
        System.out.println("Item Category: " + item.getCategory());
    }
}
```

com.sample.model

```
package com.model;

public class Item {
    private String category;
    private Float cost;

    public Item(String category, Float cost) {
        this.category = category;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public Float getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public void setCost(Float cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }
}
```

This is my pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>DroolCmonDude2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.59.0.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.59.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>7.59.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
            <version>7.59.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

And my Rules.drl at resources.rules

```
package resources.rules;

import com.model.Item;

rule "Classify Item - Low Range"
    when
        $i: Item(cost < 200)
    then
        $i.setCategory(Category.LOW_RANGE);
end
```

My kmodule.xml

```
<kmodule xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">
</kmodule>
```

***SOLUTION***

As @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas indicated the solution was to add the dependencies for drools-mvel, drools-model-compiler and sfj4 and works. This is for Drools 7>
This how my pom looks now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>DroolsAnotherChance</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.59.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>7.59.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
            <version>7.59.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-mvel</artifactId>
            <version>7.59.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-model-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>7.59.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I solve "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-can-i-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror) I don't know for sure, but your specific issue looks like you have only added the dependency for `kie-api` in your pom, but you don't have the actual kie classes/library that the kie-api depends upon to run or compile your project.

Comment: Possibly helpful in your situation where you can build the project but not run it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54304712/how-to-fix-noclassdeffounderror-kieservices-factory The short version is that the library files are not distributed with the complete project (you need to copy them manually), or you need to build a uber/fat jar (that contains all the required libraries).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @sorifiend I really apreciate. I Add more dependencies to the pom for Kie, but didn't work, I think I will have to try to copy them manually but, It's so weird, and in such small project I mean it's just knda a Hello world but I don't have success, and I need to implement drools to a very large project, I'll keep searching. But thanks for the help

Comment: Your kmodule xml is incomplete, but that's not relevant. You also don't need the kie-api at all. The question linked to by sorifiend is not relevant for modern Drools. For > 7.45 you need also either drools-mvel or drools-model-compiler. Refer to the [docs](https://docs.drools.org/latest/drools-docs/html_single/#_new_wrapper_modules) about the breaking changes introduced in that release.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas you are right!! It worked, I had to add the dependecies for slf4j and didn't need the kie-api as you said.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Technically you only need EITHER drools-mvel OR drools-model-compiler (depending on whether you're using mvel or not). In older Drools this logic was bundled directly into the drools-compiler dependency; 7.45 introduced the breaking change where it was broken out into a separate dependency which has caused all sorts of headaches.

Comment: I tried only adding one of the two but didn't work, I needed both for some reason. Thanks for the help @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I was having a bad time learning Drools hahaha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a non-backwards-compatible change to the Drools library introduced in 7.45. You can read about it in the documentation's release notes [here](https://docs.drools.org/latest/drools-docs/html_single/#_new_wrapper_modules).

Basically, starting in 7.45, the introduction of "executable models" caused mvel support to be broken out into a separate module. As a result you now need to include one of the following dependencies:

- drools-mvel-compiler
- drools-model-compiler

Which one you need depends on what you're actually doing. Prior to 7.45, the mvel compiler support was part of the drools-compiler dependency, so this extra dependency was not necessary.

(As a note, you don't need the `kie-api` dependency.)