# Maven is successfully built with the current version of a dependency, but still references to an older version

Tags: java, maven

I have the current version of the dependency successfully installed in the local mvn `.m2` registry with `mvn clean install` (confirmed by cd into `.m2` repository).

I then modified the `pom.xml` of the project to include the new version number:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xyz.lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>xyz-lib-abc-model</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

Maven was able to build successfully with `1.4.0-SNAPSHOT`, but when I accessed the project in IntelliJ, it linked to an old version (`0.1.1-SNAPSHOT`) instead of the current version.

When I checked the dependency tree using `mvn dependency:tree, I have:

```
[INFO] +- com.xyz.lib:xyz-lib-abc-model:jar:1.4.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
```

Which looks correct to me.

I have tried using `<dependencyManagement>` but then it makes the project failed to build, and failed to detect the model.

Anyone knows what's going on and how to get maven to pull the correct version?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried doing maven reimport from IntelliJ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980869/force-intellij-idea-to-reread-all-maven-dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try re-importing the dependencies from local m2 in IntelliJ like :

- Open the project view in IntelliJ
- Right click the pom.xml file and
- select Maven - Reimport If this works for you IntelliJ will add the
  dependencies to the project
- Check the if the dependencies you need    are added in File - Project
  Structure - Project Settings - Libraries    and File - Project
  Structure - Modules - Dependencies

Comment: @Katie No problem .

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue with IntelliJ.
If you don't need the old version anymore, you can cd to .m2 directory and delete the older version manually. 
But you need to keep the both versions, you can open the project as a fresh project using the pom.xml. This will solve the issue.

Comment: The old model (`0.1.1-SNAPSHOT`) is unfortunately not a local one, and is not in my local registry. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: You only need to access and delete this from the local .m2 repository in your local pc. Remote artifacts are downloaded and stored there. Idea if accessing the old version from  your local repo.

Answer (score 0):

my first guess goes to the used maven type in your IDEA  is not the one that you use in the terminal. :)

[image: IDEA preferences]
You can set up the installed maven instead of the bundled one.

---

Or another solution is that you proceed a “refresh/reimport” in pom.xml. It will investigate the classpath based on your pom.xml and refresh the ones that needed.

You should see the "Reimport button here
[image: Reimport]

If you don't see Maven at all, that means. you haven't added your project to IDEA as a Maven project.

Please then do the following
 1. Right Click on pom.xml 
 2. 2. Add as a maven project 
[image: add as a maven project]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach:

1. Close the project in IntelliJ
2. File --> Open ...
3. Find **pom.xml** of your project, not the idea project files
4. Open this pom.xml. It will re-build all the dependency model in accordance with the information found in this new pom.xml (that I assume doesn't have an old dependency anymore).

DependencyManagement section is irrelevant in this case - mention it because you've said in the question that you've tried this - so don't bother, it will save you some time :)