# Depedency Hateoas not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm following a tutorial on springboot using IntelliJ IDEA and at some point it says to add this to the `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

but then the name `spring-boot-starter-hateoas` gets red (meaning there is an error there) and when I move the mouse over it it says

> Dependency 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas:' not found

What can I do to fix this? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It probably means that you need to rebuild your maven project. On which IDE are you ?

Comment: Update your maven dependency

Comment: @FabienMIFSUD IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate. I tried building again but still...

Comment: @Eklavya Not sure how to do that, will look into it...

Comment: Are you using any IDE ?

Comment: @Eklavya IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate. I also edited it in my post.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980869/force-intellij-idea-to-reread-all-maven-dependencies

Comment: @Eklavya It worked, it was called a little different though, "Reload all Maven Projects". Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had similar errors. You have to update the maven project making sure you **force updates**

Right click on the project, scroll down to *maven* and click on *update project*.

On the window that pops up be sure to tick the **Force Update of Snapshots/Releases** option. Then click ok

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add the version to your dependency as well. Go to [Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-hateoas) and select a version and add that `dependency` snippet under `maven` to your `pom.xml`

Comment: Tried 
`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>` 
but didn't work. Except if you meant something different and I didn't get it right.