# Errors with deeplearning4j and Maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-plugin, deeplearning4j

Here is [the tutorial I'm following](https://deeplearning4j.konduit.ai/getting-started/tutorials/quickstart-with-mnist).

The pom.xml file is the default one that comes with the dl4j examples folder so there shouldn't be issues there but it still has errors.

Here's the code:

```
package org.deeplearning4j.self;
import org.deeplearning4j.datasets.iterator.impl.EmnistDataSetIterator;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.MultiLayerConfiguration;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.NeuralNetConfiguration;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.layers.DenseLayer;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.layers.OutputLayer;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.multilayer.MultiLayerNetwork;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.weights.WeightInit;
import org.nd4j.linalg.activations.Activation;
import org.nd4j.linalg.learning.config.Adam;
import org.nd4j.linalg.lossfunctions.LossFunctions;

import java.io.IOException;

public class first {
    int batchSize = 128; // how many examples to simultaneously train in the network
    EmnistDataSetIterator.Set emnistSet = EmnistDataSetIterator.Set.BALANCED;
    EmnistDataSetIterator emnistTrain;
    { try { emnistTrain = new EmnistDataSetIterator(emnistSet, batchSize, true); } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } }
    EmnistDataSetIterator emnistTest;
    { try { emnistTest = new EmnistDataSetIterator(emnistSet, batchSize, false); } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } }

    int outputNum = EmnistDataSetIterator.numLabels(emnistSet);// total output classes
    int rngSeed = 123; // integer for reproducability of a random number generator
    int numRows = 28; // number of "pixel rows" in an mnist digit
    int numColumns = 28;

    MultiLayerConfiguration conf = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
        .seed(rngSeed)
        .updater(new Adam())
        .l2(1e-4)
        .list()
        .layer(new DenseLayer.Builder()
            .nIn(numRows * numColumns) // Number of input datapoints.
            .nOut(1000) // Number of output datapoints.
            .activation(Activation.RELU) // Activation function.
            .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER) // Weight initialization.
            .build())
        .layer(new OutputLayer.Builder(LossFunctions.LossFunction.NEGATIVELOGLIKELIHOOD)
            .nIn(1000)
            .nOut(outputNum)
            .activation(Activation.SOFTMAX)
            .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER)
            .build())
        .build();

    MultiLayerNetwork network = new MultiLayerNetwork(conf);
    network.init();

    // pass a training listener that reports score every 10 iterations
    int eachIterations = 10;
    network.addListeners(new ScoreIterationListener(eachIterations));
}
```

I'm using IntelliJ.

The errors I'm getting in the class is:

Both methods called on "network" aren't recognized, both "init()" and "addListeners()" have "Cannot resolve symbol" on them. It also says on "network" that the "Field network is never used".

Additionally the int "eachIterations" has an "Unknown class" error inside of the addListeners() method.

Here's the pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!--~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~ Copyright (c) 2020 Konduit K.K.   ~ Copyright (c) 2015-2019 Skymind, Inc.   ~   ~ This program and the accompanying materials are made available under the   ~ terms of the Apache License, Version 2.0 which is available at   ~ https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.   ~   ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software  ~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT   ~ WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the   ~ License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations   ~ under the License.   ~   ~ SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~-->

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dl4j-examples</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-beta7</version>
    <name>Introduction to DL4J</name>
    <description>A set of examples introducing the DL4J framework</description>

    <properties>
        <dl4j-master.version>1.0.0-beta7</dl4j-master.version>
        <!-- Change the nd4j.backend property to nd4j-cuda-X-platform to use CUDA GPUs -->
        <!-- <nd4j.backend>nd4j-cuda-10.2-platform</nd4j.backend> -->
        <nd4j.backend>nd4j-native</nd4j.backend>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.6.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven.minimum.version>3.3.1</maven.minimum.version>
        <exec-maven-plugin.version>1.4.0</exec-maven-plugin.version>
        <maven-shade-plugin.version>2.4.3</maven-shade-plugin.version>
        <jcommon.version>1.0.23</jcommon.version>
        <jfreechart.version>1.0.13</jfreechart.version>
        <logback.version>1.1.7</logback.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
                <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.29</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>netty-common</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.48.Final</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>${nd4j.backend}</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datavec</groupId>
            <artifactId>datavec-api</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datavec</groupId>
            <artifactId>datavec-data-image</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datavec</groupId>
            <artifactId>datavec-local</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-datasets</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-zoo</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ParallelWrapper & ParallelInference live here -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-parallel-wrapper</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Used in the feedforward/classification/MLP* and feedforward/regression/RegressionMathFunctions example -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
            <version>${jfreechart.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
            <version>${jcommon.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Used for downloading data in some of the examples -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datavec</groupId>
            <artifactId>datavec-data-codec</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacv-platform</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <!-- Maven Enforcer: Ensures user has an up to date version of Maven before building -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-default</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireMavenVersion>
                                    <version>[${maven.minimum.version},)</version>
                                    <message>********** Minimum Maven Version is ${maven.minimum.version}. Please upgrade Maven before continuing (run "mvn --version" to check). **********</message>
                                </requireMavenVersion>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lewisd</groupId>
                <artifactId>lint-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.11</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
                    <onlyRunRules>
                        <rule>DuplicateDep</rule>
                        <rule>RedundantPluginVersion</rule>
                        <!-- Rules incompatible with Java 9
                        <rule>VersionProp</rule>
                        <rule>DotVersionProperty</rule> -->
                    </onlyRunRules>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pom-lint</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${exec-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-shade-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <shadedClassifierName>${shadedClassifier}</shadedClassifierName>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>org/datanucleus/**</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>reference.conf</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>com.lewisd</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>lint-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[0.0.11,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goals><goal>check</goal></goals>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build> </project>
```

The error here is "${shadedClassifier}" shadedClassifier is red and the error is: "Cannot resolve symbol 'shadedClassifier'"

So I reinstalled maven with "mvn clean install" but it still doesn't work.

Maven has installed correctly with clean install but still I have these errors.

Please any help would be appriciated. I've been stuck on this for a week and I really want to learn machine learning.

Comment: Does the code compile in the IDE or you also get the error from the compiler as well as from the editor highlighting?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing maven isn't setup properly.  I would ensure the IDE is up to date. Right clicking on the project in intellij and hitting reload is something I would consider doing. Same answer as here: [Force Intellij IDEA to reread all maven dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980869/force-intellij-idea-to-reread-all-maven-dependencies)