# Java Spring Boot - Project 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.5.0' not found errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to start working with Spring Boot. I was going to follow a tutorial, and this tutorial took me to Spring Initializr. I generated a Maven project with Java 1.8, along with only the Spring Web dependency. Then, I tried to open it in IntelliJ community edition.

However, upon opening the project, I noticed 9-10 errors within the pom file. I have tried a number of things, but nothing has worked so far. I am new to Java, so I don't know if it's a JDK issue or whatever, but on the video, it worked seamlessly for him. I will attach a screenshot.

When I type `java -version` into CMD, I get the response `java version "1.8.0_291"` for reference.

Here is a list of the errors (screenshot not working):

- Project 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.5.0' not found
- Dependency 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:' not found
- Plugin 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:' not found
- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.5.0 failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.5.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.5.0/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.5.0.pom

Each of these errors appears about 3 times. These errors are generated from a fresh Spring Initializr download, so you can get the same exact file through the website yourself, too.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: It looks like there was a network problem when the project was built that made Maven Central unavailable. Building on the command line with `-U` should cause Maven to try again.  Presumably there’s a similar option in IntelliJ that you could try.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson, could you specify what the command would be? Sorry, I am new to Java and Spring all together. Thanks!

Comment: Something like `mvnw -U package` on the command line should do the trick. Alternatively, the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980869/force-intellij-idea-to-reread-all-maven-dependencies) describe how to do the same in IntelliJ.