# Getting - package org.json does not exist - unable to use JSONArray / JSONObject

Tags: java, json, maven, intellij-idea, org.json

I am trying to write a program in Java using Maven in IntelliJ which calls an API using HttpURLConnection and parses the response using JSONArray and JSONObject. I have attempted to import the org.json JAR file, and I've updated my pom.xml to include it as a dependency, but I'm still getting the following error.

```
Test.java:1: error: package org.json does not exist
import org.json.JSONArray;
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20210307</version>
</dependency>
```

I have also tried adding the downloaded JAR file to Project Structure > Modules > Dependencies but have had no luck. Is there something else I could be overlooking here?

Comment: Have you reimported Maven after adding a dependency to pom.xml? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/delegate-build-and-run-actions-to-maven.html#maven_reimport

Answer (score 2):

Your dependency and import looks correct. Reloading all maven dependencies should resolve the issue. Check this post out: [Force Intellij IDEA to reread all maven dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980869/force-intellij-idea-to-reread-all-maven-dependencies)