# What is wrong with my structure in Java project?

Tags: java, maven, spark-java

I got a Maven project setup with Spark. I followed Spark's documentation on how to create a simple get request: http://sparkjava.com/documentation#getting-started

but I get these errors:

[image]

What can be the cause here? (I'm very new to Java and just want to create a simple API) Thanks!

Comment: If you have added the dependency to your `pom.xml` this can be an IDE related problem. Have you tried to reload the maven-project?

Comment: As @csalmhof said: You have a `maven` tab on the right side of the screen, there you should see a a reload icon (looks like this: ). Or another way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980869/force-intellij-idea-to-reread-all-maven-dependencies

Comment: Did you run a mvn clean install from the command line?

Comment: Reloading was the solution, thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for completeness here  as answer:

This is an IDE related problem from IntelliJ, which can be solved by reloading the maven project.

You can do this in several ways:

**From the maven tab**

[image]

**From the context menu**

The same effect you can achieve from the context-menu of the project (Right-click -> Maven - Reload Project)

**Searching the action**

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to find actions, and input "reload", you will find the "Reload All Maven Projects".