# Really removing a package from a Spring Boot / Maven / IntelliJ project

Tags: spring-boot, maven, kotlin, intellij-idea

I'm building a web server using Spring Boot, Kotlin and IntelliJ and am learning a lot.  I added Thymeleaf but decided later than it didn't meet my needs, removed it from the POM **and rebuilt the project**.

On startup, Thymeleaf was *still* looking for the `/templates/` folder (which I'd also removed), even though Thymeleaf was no longer a part of the project, supposedly.  A project-wide search (`shift`-`ctrl`-`F`) for *thyme*, case-folding, found nothing, so I closed the project and used the GNU `find` command-line utility to search for *thyme* in the project hierarchy.  That found references in *project*`.iml` and some `.xml` files under `.idea/libraries`.  I removed those, re-opened and rebuilt the project, and it no longer mentioned `/templates/` or Thymeleaf on startup.

So my question is:  what would have been the 'official' non-hacky way of removing the Thymeleaf package from my project?  I am now wondering what other unwanted libraries are in the project, and how I should remove them.

Comment: Did you do a clean before rebuilding?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980869/force-intellij-idea-to-reread-all-maven-dependencies?rq=1) is the answer, padded to 30 characters.