# The maven on the right side of the intellij IDEA is missing plugins and dependencies

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

1,The maven on the right side of the intellij IDEA is missing plugins and dependencies.help me This question made me cry.

2,Problem Description

```
mall
---mall-auth
    Lifecycle
    **<missing>**
    **<missing>**
---mall-common
    Lifecycle
    Plugins
    Dependencies
---mall-admin
    Lifecycle
    Plugins
    Dependencies
```

[Neither plugins nor dependencies are displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AFKD.png)

I can't display the pom text
It always prompts me "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." this is disgusting

[mall pom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AFKD.png)

[mall-common pom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7TYQ.png)

[mall-auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfXZT.png)

Comment: Which IDEA IntelliJ version do you use? Does your whole build work on plain command line?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1
Maven version 3.6.3

Comment: I don't think it's a version problem. I tried to change maven 3.6.1 and it didn't work.

Comment: Could you share pom file for mall-auth?

Comment: Is the image ok,I can't display the pom text It always prompts me "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: I would suggest to delete the `.idea` directory and import the project from scratch...

Comment: I deleted the .idea directory and re-imported the project as you suggested, but it still doesn't work, and mall-common does not show plugins and dependencies. Is there something wrong with my Maven parent-child project?

Comment: It was fine before.When I added the public dependencies to Auth-common, I realized that it was missing them

Comment: Please check idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") for errors after running "reload" from maven tool window.

Answer (score 0):

You can click right click on the project, and reload maven dependencies.

[Force Intellij IDEA to reread all maven dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980869/force-intellij-idea-to-reread-all-maven-dependencies)

Comment: I tried but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Please click the button like below.[image]

Comment: how did you add pictures in comments, why i didn't find this feature