# Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:' not found on m1 macbook

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, apple-m1

I just started using the MacBook with the M1 chip and I just git-cloned my spring boot project through IntelliJ and I have installed the same java version and set its path and SDK. Everything is great actually and it runs but I get an error in my pom.xml file that says "Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:' not found". I have installed maven through homebrew. I have set its path and I have tried the different solutions provided online but the error stays the same. Can you help[The result I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIDAU.png)

Can you please help me out

Comment: Have you run mvn command yet? I guess the plugin is not yet downloaded but run the mvn command and it will.

Comment: try running `mvn clean install` it will start downloading the plugin.

Comment: If the maven command succeeds and the error persists, try reloading. Idea sometimes has a hard time noticing changes, especially in plugins. Try restarting the idea if this doesn’t help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980869/force-intellij-idea-to-reread-all-maven-dependencies

Comment: I am getting same error in my mac m1. Did you find resolution yet?